# I can't figure out how to add Downloader Library and Licensing Library to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use [Google's Downloader Library](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#AboutLibraries) and [Application Licensing Service](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) since my app is going to use APK Expansion. But the problem is I don't know how to add those 2 libraries to Android Studio. I always import libraries to Android Studio by File -> Import Module and then I select it.

But when I do that this time, it says:

> Select modules to import

Even after I've already selected the Downloader Library or Licensing Library.

I also tried importing them by copying the directories to my app directory and then including them in gradle dependencies but that doesn't work either.

Could someone walk me through adding these 2 libraries to my Android Studio because I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I was able to import the Licensing library by following the normal approach, but was not able to add Downloader library. Have you found any other way to import it other than the way you said in the answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem in a **very** weird way.

I noticed that I can't import those 2 libraries directly to Android Studio because they are missing a lot of project files and therefore Android Studio doesn't recognize them as libraries.

I then imported both libraries to Eclipse so that everything neccessary was generated and then exported them directly to Android Studio.

That worked like a charm.

Maybe a weird way to import a library but at least it worked.

Answer (score 29):

For anyone else coming along with similar problem.

I solved it by importing module (File->New->Import Module) and selecting the licensing and the downloader library folders each time.

Note however that the .project file for downloader has a line that throws Android off (correctly):

```
android.library.reference.1=../market_licensing
```

Remove this line and the module imports fine.

Thank you Google once again for your clear instructions and clean environment!!!

BTW: What the heck are they writing in their guide
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html#AboutLibraries

> "Select the Properties tab and in Library Repository, enter the
>   library from the /extras/google/ directory (play_licensing/ for
>   the License Verification Library or
>   play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/ for the Downloader Library)."

Does that even make any sense to anyone?!

Comment: Some of the worst-written tech documentation I've ever seen is on that page

Comment: Can you please explain it in detail ?

Comment: Thanks. I was furious why Android Studio could not recognize library as a library, and all because of that silly line. Upvote!

Comment: Really helpful answer. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add a comment that the .project file for downloader should point to correct dependency:

```
android.library.reference.1=../../market_licensing/library
```

Now importing downloader will also import licensing which depends and create the correct dependency.

EDIT: That libraries are rather old. I've found new versions here:

https://github.com/google/play-apk-expansion

https://github.com/google/play-licensing

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to import library, I met same issue, and I could resolve by adding 'include ':library-directory-name'

1. copy your library directory into your project
2. add "include ':library-directory-name'" in settings.gradle file same as include ':app'