# Android - Cannot create a new library module for the License Verification Library and Downloader Library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, apk-expansion-files

I am configuring the Apk Expansion Files follow this link https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files

*5. Select the Properties tab and in Library Repository, enter the library from the /extras/google/ directory (play_licensing/ for the License Verification Library or play_apk_expansion/downloader_library/ for the Downloader Library).*

I am currently stuck on the step above. Could someone give me advice?. Thanks.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25342861/i-cant-figure-out-how-to-add-downloader-library-and-licensing-library-to-androi